# React: Any way to get a list of props.children for a specific type of child only? Without iterating through all children to manually create?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-props

Is there any way for a parent component to have a list of all child components of a certain type without manually iterating through every single child in props.children to test if they're of that type? The example below shows the question. The Parent component wants a list of all Child type components. As it stands, I have to iterate over all the props.children (and recursively through all their children) to check if any are of the Child component type. But this could be too costly. Is there some special code that can be placed within the Child and Parent component to signify that each Child component should also be placed in a list within another prop of the Parent component and not just props.children? That way I wouldn't have to iterate over every single component in props.children to find them.

This issue:

```
function Parent(props){
  /*I wish to have a list of all the components of type <Child> 
  within props.children before making it to the return function.

  I would need to iterate over all props.children and their 
  children as well, and check if its a <Child> component. 
  I would weed out all other components/elements to only have a 
  list of all <Child> components
  */

  return(
    {props.children}
  )
}

function Child(props){
  return(
    {props.children}
  )
}

function App(){
  return(
    <Parent>

      <div>Just a div, would be weeded out</div>

      <Child>special component that Im looking for</Child>

      <div> //this div would be weeded out, 
        //but the <Child> component in it must be found!
        <Child>special component that Im looking for</Child>
      </div>

    </Parent>
  )
}
```

What I desire

```
  function Parent(props){
    //somehow there is special coding within the 
    //Parent and Child components that this prop
    //(listOfChildTypeComponents) gets created so 
    //I don't have to manually iterate over all
    //props.children to create it.

    const allChildComponents = props.listOfChildTypeComponents
    return(
      {props.children}
    )
  }
```

Comment: even react doesn't do this! It treats children equally. If you want to achieve something other "than getting the list of a specific child type" please do explain your needs!

Comment: @Incepter The idea is that I may want to modify child components of a specific type before I making it to the return function. So I have to manually iterate through all children to find them. I thought maybe there's a special tag or prop or something that could be put on child components that might cause them to appear in a list under a seperate prop in the parent. I know it's very abstract. If this doesn't exist then that's fine.